# Multiple intents but Broadcast receiver only called once

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I want to perform a database operation at specific moments in time and use an alarm manager and a pending intent in conjunction with a broadcast receiver.

This works, but when there are multiple intents that the same broadcast receiver has to receive within a short timeframe (f.ex. within a minute),  onreceive() only gets called once.

```
  Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, CustomBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent2.putExtra("taskId", currentTask.getTaskId());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
            ((long) dataSource.fetchTask(task.getTaskId()).getTaskTime() * 60 * 1000), pendingIntent1);
```

and the onreceive method of the broadcastreceiver:

```
  @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    dataSource = new DataSourceClass(context);
    dataSource.open();

    int taskId = intent.getIntExtra("taskId", 0);

    dataSource.setTaskStatus(3, taskId);
    dataSource.setCatInActive(dataSource.fetchTask(taskId).getTaskCategory())
}
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `set()` you can use `setExact()` after KITKAT:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

The second parameter in `getBroadcast()` is the requestCode, which works as if it was an ID, so, each PendingIntent should have a unique requestCode (aka ID). All your `pendingIntent1`'s have the same requestCode (0), I'm not sure if that's what's causing the issue but it could be, you can set a diffrent requestCode for each pendingIntent like this:

```
    int i = sharedPrefs.getInt("i", 0);

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, CustomBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent2.putExtra("taskId", currentTask.getTaskId());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, i++, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
            ((long) dataSource.fetchTask(task.getTaskId()).getTaskTime() * 60 * 1000), pendingIntent1);

    sharedPrefs.edit.putInt("i", i).apply();
```

Comment: Spot on, this was exactly what the problem was. Thank you very much!